# Encapsulation in Redux the Right Way

Tags: redux

I'm writing a complicate app that:

1. Have a reusable encapsulated components
2. our application is composed from different data flows which sometimes hold dependency between modules and slices of states

   for example:

   customer module, contains login component, when we want to preform login we should collect information from different states and component, for example, device meta data which is used in the login process should come from the device module..

therefore a few questions arise:

1. what would be the correct and encapsulated way of creating such architecture?
2. Assuming that we have two different components; an Avatar from the customer module and a chat component from the chat module. these two are consistently showing on screen in parallel - both have their own private action creators and reducers which are responsible for the changes internally.by clicking on the user's avatar the chat should open.

what would be the optimal way of creating decoupled components that allows this data flow (between the avatar and the chat module that may or may not be present) ?

I have read the following [excellent](http://blog.javascripting.com/2016/02/02/encapsulation-in-redux/) article and I find the solution described there to be not fully encapsulated.

any ideas/comments/links/advice will be welcomed
TIA

Comment: Basically, store all application state in your reducer and connect the state you need from the global state using connect() from [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux). This kind of shared state between relatively unrelated components is exactly what the flux paradigm was designed for.

Comment: Check for example this video from Dan Abramov's video series on redux:  https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-generating-containers-with-connect-from-react-redux-visibletodolist